# Why is Spring MVC json serialization 10x slower than calling jackson manually?

Tags: spring, performance, spring-mvc, jackson

Using apachebench with "ab -k -c 50 -n 1000000" options (50 concurrent threads) shows a 10x performance difference between the following 2 methods (manual and spring-managed serialization). Is it possible to achieve the same performance via configuration of Spring serialization?

I'm running the test on Windows 7, JDK8, i7-6700. Embedded *Tomcat*, similar results with *Undertow* or *Jetty* too. A similar *WildFly 10 JAX-RS* sample apps performance yields similar results as the manual spring one, so I see no reason why Spring automatic mode should be so slow.

**Full source code:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());

  @RequestMapping(value = "/auto", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
  @ResponseBody
  public Lol automaticSerialization() {

    Lol lol = new Lol();
    lol.a = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    lol.b = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return lol;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/manual", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
  @ResponseBody
  public String manualSerialization() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Lol lol = new Lol();
    lol.a = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    lol.b = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return mapper.writeValueAsString(lol);
  }

  public static class Lol {

    String a;
    long b;

    public void setA(String a) {
      this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(long b) {
      this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
      return a;
    }

    public long getB() {
      return b;
    }
  }

}
```

Edit:
Trace of automatic serialization:
[image: Trace of automatic serialization]

Trace of manual serialization:
[image: Trace of manual serialization]

Comment: The only difference I see is executing the various HttpMessageConverter to find the jackson converter. This converter call `ObjectMapper.canSerialize` and manage `@JsonView` but honestly, I don't see why these calls can add a x10 overhead

Comment: It is really strange. I have attached some screenshots of profiling results.

Comment: Have you tried the same calls but returning lists of 100s of LOLs? I'm wondering if there's some batch optimization at play resulting in slower times than the straightforward writeValueAsString

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but there was one bug fixed in Jackson wrt `canSerialize()` call, caching (that is, caching of serializer failed), so it is worth trying to see that a recent Jackson version is being used. I don't think that explains 10x difference, but could contribute. If you can use Jackson 2.7, latest is 2.7.6.

Comment: @ Paul_R I have tried sending 50 LOLs in an ArrayList, no significant change in results. The app is a vanilla Spring Boot app, with the single class shown in this question.

Comment: @StaxMan Thank for the suggestion, but 2.7.5 and 2.8.0 show very similar results

Comment: @GeorgeStone ok then it probably is just due to overhead of dispatching by Spring MVC. Same is true for JAX-RS as well; in that case it seems to be due to many dynamic lookups made based on mime-type, re-discovery of annotations and such. Not sure if that could be same for Spring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only idea that I have is that Spring's default `ObjectMapper` is configured a bit differently than the one you use in your benchmark. Like the comments mention, you'd probably see a bit of overhead if you let Spring handle the mapping automatically but it shouldn't have more than a few percent's worth of impact.

To be sure that the comparison is fair, add this bean definition to your configuration:

```
@Bean
@Primary
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());
}
```

and replace `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());` with an autowired field:

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper mapper;
```

and see if the benchmarks return the same value.

**EDIT**

I wanted to verify this for myselt so I wrote a JMeter plan and executed each endpoint exactly 5kk times, with a 1-minute warm-up period. The results were as expected, no major differences between the approaches:

```
Label,# Samples,Average,Min,Max,Std. Dev.,Error %,Throughput,KB/sec,Avg. Bytes
Auto Request,5000000,2,0,108,5.88,0.00%,15577.3,3088.08,203.0
Manual Request,5000000,2,0,149,5.99,0.00%,15660.2,2813.94,184.0
```

The important thing to note is the throughput difference - auto's 15577.3 vs. manual's 15660.2.

[Here's my JMeter test plan](https://gist.github.com/FingolfinTEK/4e2b8491e85dbc2e2a276a2ce078c8ff), if you'd like to test it yourself, I was running on port 8081. If I find the time, I'll try another benchmarking framework, perhaps Gatling.

Comment: Thanks, tested this approach, but this has the same result.

Comment: I tried running the test through JMeter but I failed to reproduce your results, see my updated answer

Comment: JMeter returns equal results for the 2 method types, so this issue is probably an apachebench issue. Perhaps the way the connection is written to / flushed by the jackson output stream has something to do with it.

Comment: Yeah, that's most likely it.